# How do I change the XSLT provider for Spring MVC (i.e. Plug in Saxon 9.x)?

Tags: spring-mvc, xslt-2.0, saxon

I've done a google but can't see anyone talking about a solution.

Is there a proper way of plugging in Saxon so that Spring MVC uses it for its XSLT views instead of whatever comes with the JDK, which is still 1.0 ?

(Haven't tried myself, in a rush, so just wondered if anyone out there has already done this and if so how).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, but if it does make the engine pluggable then it almost certainly uses the JAXP factory mechanism to achieve it, so try it out: set the java.xml.transform.TransformerFactory property, set the jaxp.debug property, and give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as Michael says. Basically just put the Saxon jar(s) on the classpath. I imagined it could be, but didn't like to assume, and simply couldn't find a mention of anyone saying so. So now it has been mentioned hopefully others will find this useful.