# MockHttpServletResponse : Checking xml content

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces, spring-mvc-test

I am testing a controller using `MockMvc`. This is what the response looks like:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {Content-Type=[text/xml]}
        Content type = text/xml
                Body = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:diagnosisCode xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.mycompany.co.za/health" effectiveStartDate="2014-03-05T00:00:00+02:00" effectiveEndDate="2014-03-05T23:59:59.999+02:00" diagnosisId="1"><diagnosisCodeId><codingSchemaCode>irrelevant schema</codingSchemaCode><diagnosisCode>irrelevant code</diagnosisCode></diagnosisCodeId></ns2:diagnosisCode>
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

Pretty-printed version of the `Body` line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:diagnosisCode xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.mycompany.co.za/health" effectiveStartDate="2014-03-05T00:00:00+02:00" effectiveEndDate="2014-03-05T23:59:59.999+02:00" diagnosisId="1">
    <diagnosisCodeId>
        <codingSchemaCode>irrelevant schema</codingSchemaCode>
        <diagnosisCode>irrelevant code</diagnosisCode>
    </diagnosisCodeId>
</ns2:diagnosisCode>
```

The call on `MockMvc` looks like

```
mockMvc.perform(
        get("/diagnostic/diagnosisCodes/{schema}/{code}", IRRELEVANT_SCHEMA, IRRELEVANT_CODE).accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(xpath("diagnosisCodeId/diagnosisCode").string(IRRELEVANT_CODE))
        .andExpect(xpath("diagnosisCodeId/codingSchemaCode").string(IRRELEVANT_SCHEMA));
```

I am pretty sure I am misunderstanding how I'm supposed to use XPath here, but why is this assertion failing? What should my expectation look like?

```
java.lang.AssertionError: XPath diagnosisCode expected:<irrelevant code> but was:<>
```

Comment: Can you add your source XML to the question and what you expect to select with XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what the XPath context is (or whether it is the document node), but I see two possible problems and guess both apply:

- You try to match `< diagnosisCodeId/>` elements that are the root element. There are none, but they're children of `<diagnosisCode>`. Either include an axis step for the root node (probably better way) or use the `descendant-or-self` axis step `//` in front of the query.

  ```
  /diagnosisCode/diagnosisCodeId/diagnosisCode
  //diagnosisCodeId/diagnosisCode
  ```
- The document uses namespaces (for the root element). In addition to the root element problem described above, either register that namespace (better solution, but I don't know how to do this in spring MVC) or ignore it using following workaround:

  ```
  /*[local-name() = 'diagnosisCode']/diagnosisCodeId/diagnosisCode
  ```

  Which first matches all child nodes, but then limits to the ones having the apropriate element name (ignoring namespaces).

  By adding XPath 2.0 support (for example [by including Saxon as library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242708/how-do-i-change-the-xslt-provider-for-spring-mvc-i-e-plug-in-saxon-9-x)), you can also use the wildcard namespace matcher:

  ```
  /*:diagnosisCode/diagnosisCodeId/diagnosisCode
  ```

  If you register the namespace URI `http://schemas.mycompany.co.za/health` as `ns2`, the query would look like

  ```
  /ns2:diagnosisCode/diagnosisCodeId/diagnosisCode
  ```

Comment: There is also a simpler formulation of `/*[local-name() = 'diagnosisCode']/*[local-name() = 'diagnosisCodeId']/*[local-name() = 'diagnosisCode']` which is `/*:diagnosisCode/*:diagnosisCodeId/*:diagnosisCode`

Comment: Does spring mvc support XPath 2.0? [Following to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242708/how-do-i-change-the-xslt-provider-for-spring-mvc-i-e-plug-in-saxon-9-x) it seems so, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @adamretter Unfortunately that isn't working for me.

Comment: @JensErat I've got it all working now. The only thing is that the namespace prefix should only be on the root element. Please edit your answer.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that the namespaces was only used in the element and no default namespaces applied. Next time, better also add some pretty-printed version of the XML, makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for `xpath` that takes a `Map<String, String>` of namespaces:

```java
Map<String, String> ns = Map.of("ns2", "http://schemas.mycompany.co.za/health");
mockMvc.perform(get("/diagnostic/diagnosisCodes/{schema}/{code}", IRRELEVANT_SCHEMA, IRRELEVANT_CODE)
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML))
        .andExpect(xpath("ns2:diagnosisCodeId/diagnosisCode", ns).string(IRRELEVANT_CODE))
        .andExpect(xpath("ns2:diagnosisCodeId/codingSchemaCode", ns).string(IRRELEVANT_SCHEMA));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have a rest controller:

```java
    @RestController
    public class AccountController {

        @GetMapping(value = "/accounts/{acctId}" , produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,  MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
        public Account accountDetails(@PathVariable int acctId) {
            return retrieveAccount(acctId);
        }
    }
```

and in my JUnit test class:

```java
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    String accountNumber = "1234567890";
    String customerName = "John Doe";

    @Test
    public void accountDetails_XML () throws Exception
    {
        when ( accountManager.getAccount ( 0L ) ).thenReturn ( new Account ( accountNumber, customerName ) );

        mockMvc.perform ( get ( "/accounts/0" ).accept ( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE ) ).andExpect (
                                                content ().contentType ( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE ) )
                                                .andExpect ( xpath ( "Account/name" ).string ( customerName ) )
                                                .andExpect ( xpath ( "Account/number" ).string ( accountNumber ) )
                                                .andExpect ( status ().isOk () );

        verify ( accountManager ).getAccount ( 0L );

    }
```

Note: This is what the returned XML looks like:

```
    <Account>
        <entityId/>
        <number>1234567890</number>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <beneficiaries/>
        <valid>false</valid>
    </Account>
```

This is the equivalent test in JSON just for reference.

```java
    @Test
    public void accountDetails_JSON () throws Exception
    {
        when ( accountManager.getAccount ( 0L ) ).thenReturn ( new Account ( accountNumber, customerName ) );

        mockMvc.perform ( get ( "/accounts/0" ) ).andExpect ( status ().isOk () )
                                                .andExpect ( content ().contentType ( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) )
                                                .andExpect ( jsonPath ( "name" ).value ( customerName ) )
                                                .andExpect ( jsonPath ( "number" ).value ( accountNumber ) );

        verify ( accountManager ).getAccount ( 0L );
    }
```

These sites were helpful:

- https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/return-xml-json-spring-mvc/
- https://howtodoinjava.com/java/xml/xpath-attribute-evaluate/